# The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, w3c-validation

I don't know why, but I am getting the following error:

> Line 1, Column 12604: The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.

with this code I have used in my web page:

```
<pre>
   <div itemscope="">
      <img height="270" width="270" itemprop="image" title="Ladies Ultra Cotton 100% Cotton T-Shirt - Gildan 2000L" alt="Ladies Ultra Cotton 100% Cotton T-Shirt - Gildan 2000L" src="http://www.outletshirts.com/31989-home_default/ladies-ultra-cotton-100-cotton-t-shirt.jpg" class="replace-2x img-responsive">
   </div>
</pre>
```

Why would this be?

Comment: <img height="270" width="270" itemprop="image" title="Ladies Ultra Cotton 100% Cotton T-Shirt - Gildan 2000L" alt="Ladies Ultra Cotton 100% Cotton T-Shirt - Gildan 2000L" src="http://www.outletshirts.com/31989-home_default/ladies-ultra-cotton-100-cotton-t-shirt.jpg" class="replace-2x img-responsive">

Comment: put your code in question rather posting it in comment

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly provide a type these properties (name, description, image) belong to.

In Schema.org, everything is a Thing. Thing has many child types, listed under "More specific Types". Start there and choose the most specific type for your content.

For example: WebPage, Article or maybe BlogPosting.

It could look like (using WebPage as example here):

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
```